# Clojure - how to make reference to an element in a list

Tags: clojure, keyword, min

I want to know how to make reference to the smallest elements inside a series of lists that i have partitioned like so:

```
data(map(keyword :counter)querieddata)
sortedlist(sort > tosort)
part(into [] (partition-all (/ (count data) 10) sortedlist))
zi(zipmap [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i] part)
```

which gives me results like:

```
[:a(40 40 36 33) :b(33 30 27 25) :c(25 19 18 5)]
```

I want to make reference to the smallest number in each list, as for example in the lists above, I would have the number 33 returned for a, 25 for b, and so on.
I would have assumed I could have made reference to the keyword and then used apply max but I am getting an error with this code:

```
a(map(keyword :a)zi)    
minimum(apply min a)
```

Any help is appreciated greatly!

Comment: (map #(vector (first %) (apply min (second %))) (apply hash-map [:a '(40 40 36 33) :b '(33 30 27 25)]))
user=>([:a 33] [:b 25])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `min` to each element in `part` and then `zipmap` the result like you did for `zi`:

```
smallest-numbers (map (partial apply min) part)
smallest-numbers-zipped (zipmap [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i] smallest-numbers)
```

Also, there's no need to coerce `part` to a vector, unless it's specifically needed to be a vector elsewhere.  The code you've given us will work just as well if `part` is defined as `(partition-all (/ (count data) 10) sortedlist)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't look at all like valid Clojure and presuming your input is actually a map and not a vector then this would work:

```
(into {}
  (map (fn [[k v]]
         [k (apply max v)])
       {:a '(40 40 36 33)
        :b '(33 30 27 25)
        :c '(25 19 18 5)}))
; => {:a 40, :c 25, :b 33}
```

Comment: Apologies I probably should have explained that the querieddata reference is where I'm obtaining my data from - an SQL query. I then am taking a series of numbers (:counter) from the query using:      data(map(keyword :counter)querieddata). I then manipulate the data as there are varying amounts of data returned on a daily basis

Comment: why do you keep typing foo(arg) as if it meant (foo (arg)) ?

Comment: @noisesmith, I think he's intending is as `var (f args)`, as in bindings in a `let` form.

Answer (score 0):

Starting at your last result value `[:a(40 40 36 33) :b(33 30 27 25) :c(25 19 18 5)]` you can use the next function:

```
(def your-result '[:a(40 40 36 33) :b(33 30 27 25) :c(25 19 18 5)])
(->> (map vec (partition 2 your-result))
     (map #(vector (first %) (apply min (second %))))
     (into {})
     )
```

To obtain this output

```
{:a 33 :b 25 :c 5}
```

And then you can use your keywords as:

```
(:a (->> (map vec (partition 2 your-result))
      (map #(vector (first %) (apply min (second %))))
      (into {})
      ))
```

`=> 33`